# PHP Uncaught exception when trying to get the first row of an Excel table

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have a Excel table and I'm using PHPExcel to read and display it. And now I want to get the first row. So here's my code:

```
$column = ord($sheet->getHighestColumn())-64;
for($i = 0; i<$column; $i++){
    echo $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($i,1) . ' ';
}
```

And this is what I get:

```
country_code country_name Nom du pays modification_flag tag Code ISO AlphabÃ©tique 2 positions Iban O/N
```

So I have 7 columns and the output is correct but I also have an fatal error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Exception' with message 'Invalid cell coordinate [AA1' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/BICIBAN/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php:594 Stack trace: #0 /Library/WebServer/Documents/BICIBAN/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php(1218): PHPExcel_Cell::coordinateFromString('[AA1') #1 /Library/WebServer/Documents/BICIBAN/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php(1200): PHPExcel_Worksheet->createNewCell('[AA1') #2 /Library/WebServer/Documents/BICIBAN/lecture.php(112): PHPExcel_Worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(18278, 1) #3 {main} thrown in /Library/WebServer/Documents/BICIBAN/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php on line 594

I may know what it is trying to say, when I have many columns and I have for instance the AA column. So I did a function that can convert until the ZZ column but that does not correct my fatal error.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I just found what is wrong... I just forgot a $ in my for loop

```
for($i = 0; $i<$column; $i++){
```

FeelsBadMan :(